# How can I populate <select> with JSON data and display values when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, api

I've been trying to do this, but I was only able to get the data populated inside the `select` of HTML.

**2 Questions.**

**Q1.**
I was able to get the JSON data using AJAX from an API. (*using AJAX because I learned that it doesn't need the browser to refresh to fetch new data*):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  getDataJson();
});

function getDataJson(ajaxurl) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/jhucsse",  
    datatype: "json",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
  });
}
```

Next I tried to populate the select in my HTML on `OnSuccess`:

```
function onSuccess(jsonReturn) {
  $("#dropdown").empty();

  //console.log(jsonReturn);

  let dropdown = $('#dropdown');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Country</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);


// Populate dropdown with list of countries

  $.each(jsonReturn, function (key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.data).text(entry.data));
  });
  
  
    var $dropdown = $('#dropdown'),
        $objView = $('#objView'),
        $docFragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

for (var prop in jsonReturn) {
    $('<option/>', {
        val: prop,
        text: prop
    }).appendTo($docFragment);
}

$dropdown.append($docFragment);

$dropdown.on('change', function() {
    var objString = JSON.stringify(jsonReturn[$dropdown.val()]);

    objString = objString.replace(/[\{\}\[\]\"]*/ig, '');    // Remove unwanted chars
    objString = objString.replace(/\,/ig, '<br/>');         // Replace commas with new lines (i.e. br tags)

    $objView.html(objString);
});

$dropdown.trigger('change');     
    
}

//if JSON fails
function onError() {
  $("#dropdown").html("i failed.");
}
```

And It worked. But then I tried to do the next step I wanted to do which is to when I click on the name of a country it should display the rest of its JSON data with names and their values.
[How to display JSON data on click with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195065/8132485)
this isn't the exact, but close enough but it's a very different(difficult?for me) solution that I couldn't understand.

Currently my dropdown looks like this:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/SShady/L61a7uwr/9/)

Now I'm intended to do this [Populate HTML Table with Certain Items from a JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54067394/8132485)

but with all the other JSON data like this for each country [How to display JSON data on click with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195065/8132485)

How can I resolve the rest of the scripting?

**Q2.** How to reduce the AJAX fetching lag?

There's a little bit of a lag/slow that I've noticed even with fewer data. Or is it just normal?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Q1**

First of all, I prepare these 3 variables to make it simpler.

```
let jsonResponseContainer = []
let dropdown = $("#dropdown")
let objView = $("#objView")
```

Then prepare this when the document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initiate everything
    getDataJson();
  
    // Move dropdown change to standalone
    dropdown.on('change', function() {
        let chosenResponse = JSON.stringify(jsonResponseContainer[$("#dropdown").val()])
    
        // Remove unwanted chars
        chosenResponse = chosenResponse.replace(/[\{\}\[\]\"]*/ig, '');
        chosenResponse = chosenResponse.replace(/\,/ig, '<br/>');
    
        // Change objView
        objView.html(chosenResponse)
    })
});
```

Your ajax is

```
function getDataJson(ajaxurl) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/jhucsse", 
    datatype: "json",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
  });
}
```

I made a function just to populate the dropdown

```
function populateDropdown(index, data){
    let newOption = "<option value=\"" + index + "\">" + data + "</option>"
    dropdown.append(newOption)
}
```

Major changes I made

```
function onSuccess(jsonReturn) {
// Populate container with ajax return directly
jsonResponseContainer = jsonReturn

// Do what you need to do
dropdown.empty();
dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Country</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

// Populate dropdown with list of countries
  $.each(jsonReturn, function (key, entry) {
    populateDropdown(key, entry.country);
  });
}
//if JSON fails
function onError() {
  $("#objView").html("i failed.");
}
```

Notice that I copy `jsonReturn` to another variable just to make sure the data now can be accessed everywhere. Next is your on-change listener was put on a loop, I moved it out of the loop. Now, I make `<option>` with string (you may change it with fragment if you want). Pay attention I make the value with key (array key for `jsonReturn` which is the same for `jsonResponseContainer`). When the on-change listener is evoked, it just needs to retrieve from the array to `<pre>`.

**Answer for Q2**

I don't understand about it, I suppose it is not your fault.

note: I apologize if I was using the wrong grammar.